# Flat File Connection Manager Text Qualifier Setup SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, delimiter, flat-file

I am using an SSIS package with a flat file connection manager described as below on the pictures, with format: Delimited and Text qualifier as **"**. All the columns are Comma Delimited. However I have one column **ItemDescription** in my table that hold data such as **Box Dimension 2"** instead of **Box Dimension 2 in.** or **Box Dimension 2 inches**, for instance. This is causing the csv file generated to create another column whenever it hit that piont in my package. Any suggestion on how to make this work without getting another column?

[image]

[[image: 2]]]

[image]

UPDATE, Here is the raw data on a text file as output the example here is **SupplyID 929 with ItemDescription "Box Fiberboard 2"". also supplyID 525 and 888**

```
"SupplyID","ProtocolName","AssayName","ItemNumber","ItemDescription","PackagingUnits","SupplyCost","CatalogNumber","SetChildItemsToInclude","PrimaryStatus","SecondaryStatus"
    "1531","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXXXX-XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX: XXXXXX A (100% XXXXXX XXXXXX) and B (80% XXXXXX XXXXXX + 20% DMSO)","1","0","BD368632","","False","False"
    "368","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX001","XXXXXX XXXXXX","250","0.16","STP-150","","False","False"
    "369","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX002","XXXXXX XXXXXX","100","0.03","326895","","False","False"
    "370","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX003","XXXXXXXXXXX, 20 G (Insyte)","50","3.39","BD 381433 ","","False","False"
    "371","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX004","XXXXXXXXXXX, 22 G (Insyte)","50","3.39","BD 381423","","False","False"
    "372","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX006","XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX (BD)","200","1.09","BD 364880","","False","False"
    "929","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX007","Box Fiberboard 2"","1","5.41","","","True","False"
    "525","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX126","Parafilm M XXXXXX, 2" x 250 feet (Ref# PM992), 1 XXXXXX Each","1","42.12","13-374-16","","False","False"
    "888","XXXXXX","XXXXXX XXXXXX","XXXX152","XXXXXX XXXXXX, 21G w/12" XXXXXX, XXXXXX lock","50","1.65","","","False","False"
```

Comment: I tried it on my system and the output in the csv looks correct. is the " in the text one double quote or two single quotes?

Comment: Thanks @Bob Klimes It is double quotes.

Comment: Just so we're clear on what the source data looks like, could you open the source file in a text editor (notepad works) and copy out the section that is `ItemNumber` to `PackagingUnits`

Comment: The source data contains one column ItemDescription in the table that holds data such as Box Dimension 2" instead of Box Dimension 2 in.. this format depnds on another system that controlled I cannot change data in it.

Comment: You misunderstand, I want to see an example of one row, preferably one that has the 2" value in it, with the preceding and succeeding columns. Something like `1234,"Box Dimension2"",456` or `"1234","Box Dimension2"","456"` or however the source system has generated the data. There is no CSV standard so everyone has their own house rules on how this stuff works

Comment: @billinkc, sorry for the misunderstanding. I have updated my post with an example of the output. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, the raw data. Excel has interpreted the data for presentation. That's why you want to use a text editor like notepad to view the data

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**Temporary fix is convert the file to pipe "|" delimited.

**Option #2** Enclose all the column with double quote "part1,part2"comma inside the column value. In you case "Box Dimention 2,boxkalai".

Comment: I have tried option #1 already without success. 
The source data contains one column ItemDescription in the table that holds data such as Box Dimension 2" instead of Box Dimension 2 in.. this format depnds on another system that controlled I cannot change data in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without looking at the raw data. In the screenshot the most important characters are stripped away (like `,` and `"`).

If you could provide part of the raw data, we would be able to help you better. (for example: some fields could also be multiline)

> However I have one column ItemDescription in my table that hold data such as Box Dimension 2" instead of Box Dimension 2 in. or Box Dimension 2 inches, for instance. This is causing the csv file generated to create another column whenever it hit that piont in my package.

Those extra columns are almost certanly there because of extra `,` in a field that is not properly surrounded by quotes.

Some general rules:

- Quotes are (only) needed when there is a seperator inside a field. If a field is surrounded with quotes, quotes inside that field must be escaped with another quote - for example: `"27"" monitor, black"`.
- If the flatfile is really malformed, it should never be accepted because that will only bring more trouble in the long run. The only 'right' solution in that case is to 'demand' the provider of the data to send wellformed data.

Trying to 'fix' (the import of) malformed flatfiles will not only give more trouble in the long run (especially when there are regular updates of the data), but also keep more and more malformed data floating around in general (if the providers of mallformed know it gets fixed, they probably won't bother to fix it themselves).

**edit** (looking at raw data now)

I had a look at the raw data, and indeed the data is malformed:

`,"Box Fiberboard 2"",` should be `,"Box Fiberboard 2""",`

and `,"Needles Butterfly, 21G w/12" tubing, luer lock",` should be `,"Needles Butterfly, 21G w/12"" tubing, luer lock",` for example.

So, ideally this data should be fixed at the source.

In case that is not possible, there might be some kind of hack (but not reccommended) which is to split the lines on `","` - since all fields are quoted you could get away with it, but you would have to trim the first and last field for the remaining `"`.